# Delete mapping within a mapping

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping, solidity-0.5.x

I have a mapping with the following structure:

```
mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => SOME_STRUCT)) public submissions;
```

`delete submissions[uint256]` is not allowed(compiler error).

`delete submissions[uint256][msg.sender]`  is allowed(no compiler error).

The remove function needs to be restricted i.e only the manager of the contract is allowed to delete from the submissions mapping. But the address in the inner mapping serves as the key and is an arbitrary address. How would i go about deleting the inner mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#delete):

> `delete a` assigns the initial value for the type to `a`, i.e. for integers it is equivalent to `a = 0`, but it can also be used on arrays, where it assigns a dynamic array of length zero or a static array of the same length with all elements set to their initial value. `delete a[x]` deletes the item at index `x` of the array and leaves all other elements and the length of the array untouched. This especially means that it leaves a gap in the array. If you plan to remove items, a mapping is probably a better choice.
>
> For structs, it assigns a struct with all members reset. In other words, the value of `a` after `delete a` is the same as if a would be declared without assignment, with the following caveat:
>
> `delete` has no effect on mappings (as the keys of mappings may be arbitrary and are generally unknown). So if you delete a struct, it will reset all members that are not mappings and also recurse into the members unless they are mappings. However, individual keys and what they map to can be deleted: If `a` is a mapping, then `delete a[x]` will delete the value stored at `x`.

---

To answer your question `How would i go about deleting the inner mapping?`:

The entity authorized to delete the mapping should either store the mapping keys, or receive them as input when it is requested to initiate the process.

Comment: The removal process is never initiated by the owner of the address used as the key in the inner mapping. Basically the scenario is that i'd like to remove everything associated with the `uint256` used as the key in the outer mapping. I suppose i could just leave it in there though, since the key can never be used again but leaving stuff in there as garbage is bad practice?

Comment: @Conviley: You could earn gas by deleting those (though you'll actually earn gas only if you do it from a transaction which spends at least twice more).

Comment: Yeah that's what i though about - the gas refund. But i think you're right in the sense that it will cost more to delete than the refund itself. Because then i'd have to save all the addresses and link them to the outer uint256 key and then like iterate through all of them to remove their entry in the inner mapping. I'll just leave it as garbage value then i guess :/

Comment: What I meant to say is that you don't get refund if it's more than (even half of) the cost of the rest of the transaction, i.e., a transaction will obviously not end up with the miner paying you instead of vice-versa. And of course, I haven't even taken the cost of storing the keys on-chain for specifically for that purpose (I've assumed that you would save them on your off-chain server and pass them to the manager when you want to delete them from the mapping).

Comment: yeah saving them off chain could be something but it's a bit outside the scope of my little project, I believe I'll just leave the values there it won't cause a problem since the keys cannot be reused. Nevertheless, I'll go ahead and accept your answer because I feel it is indeed correct! :)